# How URL of the DoH server resolves into ip address?

Tags: dns

I know that before we can get content of the URL example.com we need to know its ip address. For that we use DNS server which ip address we know.

But in some resources ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS#/media/File:DNS_over_HTTPS_information_on_Firefox_89_screenshot.png), [adguard](https://kb.adguard.com/en/general/dns-providers), [cloudflare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/enable-private-dns-with-1-1-1-1-on-android-9-pie/#dnsinanipv6world)) address for DNS over HTTPS (DOH) server is URL. (Same for DNS over TLS (DoT))

And I would like to clarify a few questions for myself:

- Is it possible to specify DoH or DoT adresses without URL and only with ip?
- If the answer to the previous question is yes, why do we need to use URLs for this?
- Which DNS is used to transform `1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com` into `1.1.1.1`?

Comment: It is a very good question... but completely offtopic here as not related to programming. Note that you are dealing with very "recent/advanced" stuff. "DDR" is one way to discover the proper resolver to use, look at this article for an example: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/making-doh-discoverable-introducing-ddr/ba-p/2887289 ; this uses the newer `SVCB` DNS records. A DoH endpoint HAS to be an URL. DoH specification is RFC 8484. See "3.  Selection of DoH Server" in it.